# Difference between display and fields directives in CloudWatch Logs Insights query syntax

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

What is the difference between `display` and `fields` directives in CloudWatch Logs Insights query syntax?

These are descriptions from [the AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CWL_QuerySyntax.html#CWL_QuerySyntax-commnds) that look very similar to me :

> **`display:`** Specifies which fields to display in the query results.
>
> **`fields:`** Retrieves the specified fields from log events for display.

As an example, I have logs stored in Cloudwatch in this structure (with these fields):

- `@timestamp`
- `@message`
- `stream` (`stdout`|`stderr`)
- `kubernetes.namespace_name`
- ...

Here are examples of valid queries that confuse me:

1. I can display any non-retrieved field:

```
limit 8
| display @message, stream
```

2. I can display a field even if I haven't specified it in `fields`.

```
fields @message, stream
| limit 8
| display @message, stream, kubernetes.namespace_name
```

3. It doesn't matter if I specify a field in `fields` when parsing:

```
fields @message
| parse @message "[*] *" as loggingType, loggingMessage
| display loggingMessage
```

```
parse @message "[*] *" as loggingType, loggingMessage
| display loggingMessage
```

What is the meaning of the `fields` directive? Wouldn't it be enough to just use `display`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference in `fields` and `display` commands is that `fields` behavior is cumulative and display is not (replace-like behavior).

From the [CloudWatch Logs Insights query syntax guideline](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CWL_QuerySyntax.html):

> If your query contains multiple fields commands and doesn't include a display command, you'll display all of the fields that are specified in the fields commands.

So a `display` command would replace the output defined by any preceding `display` or `fields` commands (or any other command that defines ephemeral fields), and the `fields` would add to the currently defined output.

Examples:

1. Returns @timestamp, @message, @logStream, @log fields

```
fields @timestamp, @message, @logStream, @log
| sort @timestamp desc
| limit 20
```

2. Returns @message

```
fields @timestamp, @message, @logStream, @log
| sort @timestamp desc
| limit 20
| display @message
```

3. Returns @message, requestId, text, hasRequestId

```
fields @timestamp, @message, @logStream, @log
| sort @timestamp desc
| limit 20
| display @message
| parse @message "(*) *" as requestId, text
| fields !isblank("requestId") as hasRequestId
```

The last example defines ephemeral fields using `parse` command (these do not have `@` in the beginning) and expression field defined by last `fields` command

Answer (score 1):

By my reading of the documentation, `fields` would be used during the query, and `display` only for presentation at the end. `display` is also only effective once (the last invocation is used).

What I mean is that in the example:

```
fields concat(Operation, '-', StatusCode) as opStatus
```

I don't think you could use `display` to do the same thing.

You might want to gather multiple fields to calculate a value (using `fields`), or filter some fields for speed, but only display the final result at the end.